# GPG encryption working from mac terminal but not from java Runtime.getRuntime().exec()

Tags: java, encryption, gnupg

Running gpg encryption from mac terminal encrypting file properly, below statement works fine:

```
gpg --homedir /Users/schoudhary5/.gnupg/  -i --yes -o /Users/schoudhary5/Documents/testpgp/pgp_1_out.txt -r "test_gpg@gmail.com"  --batch --encrypt --armour --sign --passphrase skch_123! /Users/schoudhary5/Documents/testpgp/pgp_1.txt
```

But when I run same command from java using below statement gives error:

```
    Runtime.getRuntime().exec( "gpg --homedir /Users/schoudhary5/.gnupg/  -i --yes -o /Users/schoudhary5/Documents/testpgp/pgp_1_out.txt -r \"test_gpg@gmail.com\"  --batch --encrypt --armour --sign --passphrase skch_123! /Users/schoudhary5/Documents/testpgp/pgp_1.txt")
```

> gpg: "test_gpg@gmail.com": skipped: No public key gpg:
>   /Users/schoudhary5/Documents/testpgp/pgp_1.txt: sign+encrypt failed:
>   No public key

When search same key from java its searchable:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec( "gpg --list-keys test_gpg@gmail.com");
```

output:

> pub   4096R/5056535C 2016-11-23 [expires: 2020-11-23] uid
>   [ultimate] test_gpg  sub   4096R/8ABE5AD1
>   2016-11-23 [expires: 2020-11-23]

Got stuck at it, any help is well appreciated, already Thanks.

Comment: Java `Runtime` is not a shell; it does not remove quotes like shells do when wordsplitting the command it runs, so you are asking for the keyid `"test_gpg@email"` INCLUDING THE QUOTES and that keyid does not exist, as the error message told you. Omit the quotes, as you did in the case that works. Even better pass the program name and each argument separately as varargs.

Comment: Thanks Dave, it worked.